# Customizing Outlook 2013 to avoid message content from email listing

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2013

I need to make the listing of emails to be more compact. Inorder to make it compact, I need to remove the message section (first line of message as highlighted in yellow in the image below) from the listing. How can we achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Is your question how to turn off Preview?

Comment: @sunk818 Yes, it was... But I didn't know the correct terminology for that

Comment: That's okay. Other Google searches will find it now because I wrote Preview... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Outlook 2013:

- Go to View Ribbon.
- Under Message Preview, change from 1 Line to Off.

Decide if you want this to be applied to all your folders, or just the Current Folder.

[image]